# Perfect Numbers Display Java

Tags: java

I have the following question for Homework

> If a number is equal to the sum of all of its factors except itself, it is a perfect number. For example, 6 is a perfect number since 6 = 1 + 2 + 3.
>
> Write a program that takes an input number and displays all perfect numbers up to and including that number.

and this is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class perfectnumbers
 {
public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   int externalNumber;
 
   int internalNumber;
   int internalTotal = 0;
   
   System.out.println("Input Number");
   externalNumber = console.nextInt();
   
   while (externalNumber > 0) {
       internalNumber = externalNumber;
       while (internalNumber > 0) {
           internalNumber = internalNumber - 1;
           internalTotal = internalNumber + internalTotal;
        }
        if (internalTotal == externalNumber) {
            System.out.println(internalTotal);
        }
        externalNumber = externalNumber - 1;
        internalTotal = 0;
    }
}
}
```

But for some Reason when ever I enter a number only 3 gets outputted... Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue?

Comment: Yes i did, and every number just gives me 3 and only 3

Comment: Where do you check if it is a factor?

Comment: oh wait @gonzo Im dumb i didn't do factors i just subtracted thanx

Comment: Interesting problem: note that the *efficiency* ("..displays **all** perfect numbers...") really matters here. What if we are given, say, `2000000000` (up and including **two billions**)?

Answer (score 2):

*Perfect* numbers (like other *perfect* things) are very *scarce* ones

https://oeis.org/A000396

they are (within the `int` range):

```
6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336
```

(only *three more* `8589869056, 137438691328, 2305843008139952128` when working with `long`).

So you can implement it like that:

```
  private static int[] perfectNumbers = new int[] {
    6, 28, 496, 8128, 33550336
  };

  private static void displayPerfects(int upTo) {
    for (int item : perfectNumbers) 
      if (item > upTo)
        break;
      else {
        System.out.print(item); 
        System.out.println();
      }
  }

  ...

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    ...
    System.out.println("Input Number");
    ...
    externalNumber = console.nextInt();
    ...
    displayPerfects(externalNumber);
  }
```

Please note, that *efficiency* really *matters* in your case, e.g. how much time does it take if your're given, say, `2000000000`? All you have to do is to test at most *five values*.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I was the downvoter (I reverted it). Your answer is perfect, but the OP's request concerns an homework, and I think that your solution goes beyond the didactic purpose of the assignment. Cheers.

Comment: @Andrea: As I can see, the home task is dedicated to *prime factors decomposition*, and the solution to be accepted has to *sum up factors*. However, in practice, we should *never* implement that way because of *efficency* (input like *1 billion* will froze the system forever). So I don't think that I've *spoilt the fun*: I've given a
*reference code* for testing, shown the working i.e. *practical solution*, but *haven't done* the homework (I doubt if my routine will *be accepted*).

Comment: Yes, I got your point and I agree about the efficiency aspect! In fact, I think that a request of this kind is also bad suited for a class' assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You never check for a factor. Do something like this:

```
while (externalNumber > 0) {
    internalNumber = externalNumber-1;  //Make sure to subtract one here
    while (internalNumber > 1) { //Change this to 1 so you don't divide by 0
        internalNumber = internalNumber - 1;
        if (externalNumber%internalNumber==0){ //Check for factor
            internalTotal = internalNumber + internalTotal;
        }
    }
    if (internalTotal == externalNumber) {
        System.out.println(internalTotal);
    }
    externalNumber = externalNumber - 1;
    internalTotal = 0;
}
```

Comment: *Efficiency* does matter in this problem: imagine, that you're given, say, `2000000000` - how much time does program take to "displays all perfect numbers up to and including that number"? You've *amended* the error by the problem *requires more*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yup I do agree. I was just answering OP's question of why "only 3 gets outputted..."